# Children of canvas objects do not register OnMouseUpAsButton

Tags: unity, c#

Objects I create inside my canvas do not register the `OnMouseUpAsButton()` event. I tried doing it on an empty project and it doesn't work so I guess I'm misunderstanding how something works. That being said, objects inside game world register event properly. I tried reading documentation but I still don't get why this is happening.

My code (the only code used in the project)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class test_click : MonoBehaviour {

void OnMouseUpAsButton()
{
    Debug.Log("Mouse up test click");
}

public void Thisworks()
{
    Debug.Log("yes");
}

void Start () {}
void Update () {}
}
```

My project objects:
[image]

I have spent the last 12 work hours searching for causes of this problem so I'm sure it is something absolutely obvious yet I just can't see it.